Network Error in merging contacts possibly
I'm getting a Network Error when editing activities for ONE specific civicase record. I'm not getting this error from other contacts/cases. The Network Error is "Unable to reach the server. Please refresh this page in your browser and try again." There's no issue with viewing the activity, just when I try to edit the activity.
I checked the Drupal logging reports and I'm getting a string of warnings:
ValueError: array_combine(): Argument #1 ($keys) and argument #2 ($values) must have the same number of elements in array_combine() (line 220 of /sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Case/Form/Activity.php).

Warning: Undefined array key "qs" in content_67173911e52bd7_83543831() (line 71 of /sites/default/files/civicrm/templates_c/en_US/71/3d/c5/713dc5686159d9218530130f6bccb1cc9583be49_0.file_formButtons.tpl.php).

Warning: Undefined array key "url" in content_67173911e52bd7_83543831() (line 71 of /sites/default/files/civicrm/templates_c/en_US/71/3d/c5/713dc5686159d9218530130f6bccb1cc9583be49_0.file_formButtons.tpl.php).

Config Log says:
2024-10-21 19:17:48-0700  [warning] I'm kinda confused - how did we get here? Caller: CRM_Core_Form::buildForm
Array
(
    [civi.tag] => deprecated
)

Does this seem like an issue with the contact merging?

Look at the response in the browser dev console on the network tab. It will have the error there.

Thanks, Demerit! Found the issue. The apostrophe in the name field is throwing the network error. Once it is resolved, editing the civicase activity now works again. Filed a bug here: https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/issues/5558
